# CFIMAP error - This operation is not allowed on a closed folder

Tags: coldfusion, gmail, lucee

I'm trying to connect and download email (gmail) through cfimap and always get the error. The first error that I always get is : **there is no connection available with name [imapgmail]**. After I reload again the second error that showed is : **This operation is not allowed on a closed folder.**

I used coldfusion on lucee server. This is my first time using the cfimap on lucee.

```
<cfimap
    server = "[server name]"
    username = "[username]"
    folder = "INBOX"
    action="open"
    secure="yes"
    port=993
    password = "[password]"
    connection = "imapgmail"
    timeout="2400">

<cfimap
    action="getAll"
    connection="imapgmail"
    name="qHeaders">

<cfquery name="qEmail" dbtype="query">
    select * from qHeaders
</cfquery>
```

I expect to success connecting and get the query of all the email on gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is that you are trying to open the folder in `action="open"` itself. I don't think that will work. You'll  need to add `folder = "INBOX"` to your `action="getAll"` call to open folder after the connection is established.

```
<cfimap action="getAll" folder="Inbox" connection="imapgmail" name="qHeaders">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i already tried that but didn't worked.. so i used the custom tag https://github.com/Tropicalista/lucee-cfimap and it's work like a magic :)